# Simple proof for the result:$a$ is a removable singularity of $e^f$ iff $a$ is a removable singularity of $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic in $0<|z-a|<R$ for some $R>0$.

Then **$a$ is a removable singularity of $e^f$ $\iff$ $a$ is a removable singularity of $f$**.

**Proof**:
that $a$ is a removable singularity of $f$ implies $a$ is a removable singularity of $e^f$ is clear.

For the other direction:
for any $0<r<R$,
by the Argument Principle:
$$\int_{|z-a|=r}\frac{\left(e^{f(z)}\right)'}{e^{f(z)}}\,dz
=\int_{|z-a|=r}f'(z)\,dz = 0,$$
and this implies that $e^{f(z)}$ has no zero at $a$.

If $e^{f(z)}$ has a removable singularity at $a$,
then $e^{f(z)}$ is analytic in the disk $|z-a|<R$,
and
$$e^{f(a)}=\lim_{z\to a}e^{f(z)},\qquad e^{f(z)}\neq 0,\quad |z-a|<R.$$
Let $F(z)=e^{f(z)}$, then
$f'(z)=F'(z)e^{-f(z)}$
is analytic in $|z-a|<R$.
So $f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $a$.

The proof above uses the "Argument Principle", it is seems to use a "big" tool to prove this "small" result.
What I want to say is that: is there a "simple" method to prove this "small" result,
any helps and hints will welcome!

Comment: @Martin R  thank you. But the link ( https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2218767/42969 ) also uses "Argument Principle". What I want is to avoid using the “argument principle”.

Comment: Can you please tell how if the integral by argument principle coming out zero implies that $e^{f(z})$ has no zeroes? Can't it happen that it has equal number of zeroes and poles?

Comment: @Tim  $e^f$ is analytic in $0<|z-a|<R$, and has no zero in $0<|z-a|<R$. So $e^f$ has at most one zero and one pole in $|z-a|<R$, only possible at the point $z=a.$

Comment: got it !! So, the only possibility is zero at a but how does argument principle is used in deducing that no zeroes are at z=a also? Kindly explain.

Comment: I think you shoud know "Argument Principle " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $e^f$ has a removable singularity at $a$ then $e^f = g$ where $g$ is holomorphic in $|z-a| < R$. In particular, $g$ is locally bounded, so that
$$
 |g(z)| < K \quad \text{for } |z - a| < R/2 \, .
$$
for some real constant $K > 0$. It follows that for $ 0 < |z-a| < R/2$
$$
 \operatorname{Re}f(z) = \log |g(z)| < \log K  
\implies \operatorname{Re} (\log K - f(z)) > 0  \, .
$$
Now consider the function $h(z) = T(\log K - f(z))$ where $T(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is the Möbius transformation which maps the right halfplane onto the unit disk.

- [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem)
  shows that $h$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$.
- The [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) shows that the continuation function $\hat h$ satisfies $\hat h(a) \ne 1$.

Then
$$
 \hat f(z) = \log K - T^{-1}(\hat h(z)) = \log K - \frac{1+\hat h(z)}{1-\hat h(z)}
$$
is an analytic continuation of $f$ at $z=a$, i.e. $f$ has a removable singularity at that point.

Comment: Some more argument should be added: $\left| \frac{1}{1+\log K - f(z)} \right| \le 1 $  implies $a$ is a removable singularity of $ \frac{1}{1+\log K - f(z)}$. But it may be $f$ has a pole at $a$.  Maybe you should point out that $\left| \frac{1}{1+\log K - f(z)} \right|\geq m>0.$

Comment: @Riemann: I hope that the argument is complete now.

Comment: The key point is your claim**The open mapping principle shows that the continuation function $\hat h$ satisfies $\hat h(0)≠0$**, I think You'd better explain carefully!

Comment: @Riemann: $w=0$ is a boundary point of the disk $B$.

Comment: Yes，I know you idea!

Comment: @Riemann: Btw, an alternative (if you like that better) would be to consider $H(z) = T(\log K - f(z))$ where $T(z) = (z-1)/(z+1)$ is the Möbius transformation which maps the right halfplane onto the unit disk. Then $H$ is bounded and the maximum modulus principle shows that $H(0) \ne 1$, so that $f(z) = \log K - T^{-1}(H(z))$ is the analytic continuation of $f$.

Comment: Yes , thank you, it is very kind of you!

Comment: @Riemann: Are you satisfied with the answer now? Please let me know if anything is still unclear!

Comment: Thank you very, very nice proof!  very very clear.

Comment: @Riemann: I don't want to push you, but you *might* consider to *accept* the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Yes，You deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $a$ is a removable singularity of $f$ implies $a$ is a removable singularity of $e^f$ is clear.

Now suppose $e^{f(z)}$ has a removable singularity at $a$, that is to say
$$\lim_{z\to a}e^{f(z)}=A\in\mathbb{C}.$$
Then there exists $0<\delta_0<R,n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that
$$e^{f(z)}=(z-a)^n\varphi(z),\quad\forall 0<|z-a|<\delta_0,$$
where the function $\varphi$ is holomorphic in disk $|z-a|<\delta_0$
and $\varphi(z)\neq0$.

So when $0<|z-a|<\delta_0$, we have
$$f'(z)=\frac{(e^{f(z)})'}{e^{f(z)}}=\frac{n}{z-a}+\frac{\varphi'(z)}{\varphi(z)}.$$
This implies that $f'(z)$ has either a removable singularity at $a$ (when $n=0$) or a simple pole at $a$ (when $n\geq1$). But the derivative function $f'$ cannot have a simple pole (due to the following facts)! So we have that $f'(z)$ has a removable singularity at $a$, and so does $f$ (due to the following facts).

> Some facts used above:
> If $f$ has a removable singularity at $a$, then $f'$ a removable singularity at $a$;
> If $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $a$, then $f'$ has a pole of order $n+1$ at $a$;
> If $f$ has essential singularity at $a$, then $f$ has essential singularity at $a$ ,too.