# $f$ has an isolated singularity at a point a then $e^{f} $ can't have pole at $a.$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

This question was part of an assignment that couldn't be discussed due to the pandemic.

> Question: Let $f$ have an isolated singularity at a point $a$. Prove that $e^{f}$ cannot have a pole at point $a$.

> Attempt: Let on the contrary it has a pole of the order say $k.$ Then $e^f {(z-a)^k}$ is analytic at a and  $\lim_{z\to a} f(z) = M$.

But I am unable to see a contradiction based on this.

Can someone please tell which result should I use to obtain a contradiction?

Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your answer? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827089/simple-proof-for-the-resulta-is-a-removable-singularity-of-ef-iff-a-is-a/3827118#3827118

Comment: If the singularity of $f$ at $a$ is removable, then so is that of $e^f$ at $a.$ If the singularity of $f$ at $a$ is a pole, I'd try to show that $e^f$ has an essential singularity at $a. \qquad$